# Setting the same bar/grid width for multiple barplots arranged together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, width

So I am trying to arrange four bar plots together so I can visually compare their values for a range of sites throughout different periods that I am analyzing. As the data comes from four different datasets (one for each period) I have tried to do this by making a separate plot for each period that I am looking at and then arranging them together with ggarrange, but one of them (Results4) has wider bars (and gridlines) than the rest of them.

I just can't seem to figure out how I can make sure that the bars are all the same width for each of the plots, so I hope anyone here has an idea!

This is what I have:

```
Results1 <-  ggplot(DataPC, aes(SITE, PS_score, group = 1)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "#BC3F4A", width = 1.00) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 10, angle = 75, hjust = 1), panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.75)) +
  labs(y = "PS Score") + 
  ylim(0, 5)

Results2 <-  ggplot(DataEC, aes(SITE, PS_score, group = 1)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "#BC3F4A", width = 1.00) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 10, angle = 75, hjust = 1), panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.75)) +
  labs(y = "PS Score") + 
  ylim(0, 5)

Results3 <-  ggplot(DataLC, aes(SITE, PS_score, group = 1)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "#BC3F4A", width = 1.00) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 10, angle = 75, hjust = 1), panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.75)) +
  labs(y = "PS Score") + 
  ylim(0, 5)

Results4 <-  ggplot(DataTC, aes(SITE, PS_score, group = 1)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "white", fill = "#BC3F4A", width = 1.00) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size = 10, angle = 75, hjust = 1), panel.grid = element_line(size = 0.75)) +
  labs(y = "PS Score") + 
  ylim(0, 5) 


ggarrange(Results1, Results2, Results3, Results4,
                    labels = c("Preclassic", "Early Classic", "Late Classic", "Terminal Classic"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: The easiest option would be create one data.frame from your four using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows` and afterwards use faceting. Second option would be to fix the limits of the scales so that they are same for each of your plots.

Comment: +1 for combining datasets and then using faceting. However one additional point to consider is treating the `SITE` as a `factor` to enforce inclusion of those values whether or not there were observations in that category.

Answer (score 1):

As stefan suggested in the comments, it's probably easiest to just combine your datasets into a single `data.frame` and then plot using faceting. This allows you to (optionally) enforce a shared `x` axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- tibble(site = letters[1:4], count = sample(25, 4))
d2 <- tibble(site = letters[3:6], count = sample(25, 4))

bind_rows(
  d1 %>% mutate(category = "1"),
  d2 %>% mutate(category = "2")
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(site, count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~category)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>